# Keras custom loss function. How to know which output samples are currently called in the loss funciton

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I an building a custom loss function in `keras` where I want to manipulate the `y_true` and `y_pred` before calling `mean_absolute_error()`. This manipulation involves knowing which sample the current `y_true` is, therefore,  I can easily add another column to the output which will have a sequential index. So I have

- `outputs[:,0]`  which is the acual output variable for all the samples.
- `outputs[:,1]` a sequential index which I do not want to predict but just use in my custom loss function

  ```
   def loss(y_true, y_pred):

       for i in range(len(y_true)):
           index = y_true[i, 1]
           # some manipulations involving the index
       return mean_absolute_error(new_true, new_pred)
  ```

How can I achieve the above in a way that the model ignores the index column output and does not try to predict it as well.

#### There might be a better solution to my problem. My ultimate goal is to know which sample output(s) are currently in the loss function (by an index).

Comment: What would happen you simply predict a single output?  If keras compains about the shape mismatch between true and pred, then how about you concat an arbitrary dimension, say using tf.ones?  Since that added column is not used the loss, it won't affect your learning.

Comment: From what I can tell, you're doing things fine. What are you hoping to do differently? You might be able to do things more efficiently, but a more complete example would be needed to really tell.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
def customLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    
    # you can do your preprocessing here

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
             index = y_true[i, 1]
             # some manipulations involving the index
        return mean_absolute_error(new_true, new_pred)


    return loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: which `y_true` and `y_pred` are in the parameters of the outer function?

Comment: Let me ask, you want to know how to do manipulation or where to do manipulation. The above answer tells you where you can do your manipulations. And id you want to know how to do manipulation. You have to provide more information like shape of your data, your expected output with an example.